# Difference in program behavior with different make files

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I have this OCaml program

```
open Core.Std;;
open Printf;;

let all l = List.fold ~f:(&&) ~init:true l;;

let any l = List.fold ~f:(||) ~init:false l;;

let main () = let bools = [true; false; true; true; false; true] in
  printf "%b %b\n" (all bools) (any bools);;
main();;
```

And then two make files, the first is

```
all: a.out
    @true

a.out: fold.cmx
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -linkpkg -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.cmx

fold.cmx: fold.ml fold.cmi
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -c fold.cmx -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.ml

fold.cmi: fold.mli
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -c -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.mli

fold.mli: fold.ml
    ocamlfind ocamlc -i -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.ml > fold.mli

clean:
    @rm *.cmx *.cmi *.o tests 2>/dev/null || true
```

Which produces an a.out that gives the expected output of `false true`.
The second is

```
all: fold
    @true

fold: fold.cmx
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -o fold -linkpkg -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.cmx

fold.cmx: fold.ml fold.cmi
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -c fold.cmx -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.ml

fold.cmi: fold.mli
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -c -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.mli

fold.mli: fold.ml
    ocamlfind ocamlc -i -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 fold.ml > fold.mli

clean:
    @rm *.cmx *.cmi *.o tests 2>/dev/null || true
```

which produces a fold that on my machine, hangs without output. The only difference between the two is that one of them puts its output in fold and the other puts it in a.out. The version numbers for my ocaml, ocamlc, ocamlopt, and ocamlfind are all 4.02.1 and `opam show core` says it's version 112.06.01. Any of you guys know what's causing the difference?

Comment: If you are fond of makefiles, maybe you can try [BSD Owl Scripts](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl/wiki/DevelopOCamlSoftware), a set of makefiles supporting OCaml. They work with [BSD Make](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl/wiki/Install).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the standard fold program. Try ./fold.